# How do I read a csv of national data, where first column is "state", second "town", and sum columns by state? (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, sum

Every day I create a csv that looks something like this.

| Sector | Code | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sect1 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | CodeA | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeB | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeC | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeD | data | data | data | data |
| Sect2 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | CodeE | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeF | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeG | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeH | data | data | data | data |
| Sect3 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | CodeI | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeJ | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeK | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeL | data | data | data | data |
| SectN |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | CodeX | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeY | data | data | data | data |
|  | CodeZ | data | data | data | data |

Note the blank cells: the whole row after the sector name, and the 'sector' column before each code.

Id like to read the csv and EITHER:

1. Sum the columns by sector, creating a dataframe that should look something like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sector1 | col1total | col2total | col3total | col4total |
| Sector2 | col1total | col2total | col3total | col4total |
| Sector3 | col1total | col2total | col3total | col4total |
| SectorN | col1total | col2total | col3total | col4total |

or

2. Split the csv into "sector" dataframes and work with each one individually.

Im a noob and might have bitten off more than I can chew! Currently Im separating the original csv into sector csvs and summing that way using the following code, but as you can imagine its time consuming. Its not really relevant to my question, but heres the code I use:

import pandas

with open('D:\Libraries\Downloads\igcxtest.csv', 'r') as fileObject:
reader_object = pandas.read_csv(fileObject, delimiter=';', decimal=',', header=0, names=('Noticia','Ativo','Variacao','Maximo',
'Ultimo','Minimo','Negocios','Semana',
'Mes','3 meses','6 meses','12 meses',
'Volume','Fourpercent','eightpercent',
'twelvepercent','plus25m','plus25q',
'plus50m','plus50q','minusfourpercent',
'minuseightpercent','minustwelvepercent',
'minus25m','minus25q','minus50m','minus50q',
'weekhigh','Twoweekhigh','Threeweekhigh',
'Threemthhigh','Yearhigh','weeklow',
'Twoweeklow','Threeweeklow','Threemthlow',
'Yearlow','Over200','Over50','Over21','Grafico'))
# print(reader_object)
reader_object.drop(['Noticia', 'Maximo', 'Ultimo','Minimo','Negocios','Semana','Mes','3 meses','6 meses','12 meses','Grafico'], axis=1, inplace=True)
#print(reader_object)
print(reader_object['Threemthhigh'])

```
reader_object['up_or_down'] = reader_object['Variacao'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else (-1 if x < 0 else 0))
#Calculate ups and downs
ups = 0
downs = 0
up_down = []
for val in reader_object['Variacao']:
    if val >0:
        ups+=1
    elif val < 0:
        downs+=1
up_down = [ups, downs]
print(up_down)

#Calculate cumulative volume
reader_object['Volume'] = reader_object['Volume'] * reader_object['up_or_down']
#print(reader_object)
vol = 0
for v in reader_object['Volume']:
    vol += v

reader_object.drop(['Variacao', 'up_or_down'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reader_object)
#print(ups, downs, vol)

#Sum columns
sums = reader_object.sum(numeric_only=True)
print(sums)
sums_list = []
x=0
for x in sums:
    sums_list.append(x)
sums_list = up_down + sums_list
print(sums_list)
sum_df = pandas.DataFrame(sums_list).T
#print(sum_df)
sum_df.to_csv('D:\Libraries\Downloads\sums.csv')
```

I cant find info on ways to read the original csv, and split it by using (I imagine) keywords in rows ("sectorN") or by numbers of lines (how many "codes" in each "sector") first.

Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Ugh. That's a horrible file format. They should just put the state in every row, not as a section heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

1. Read the csv into a dataframe
2. Forward-fill the State column `df['State'].fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)`
3. Filter out rows where Town is null `df2 = df.query('Town is not null')`
4. Aggregate / group by State and Town, and sum each of the measure columns `df3 = df2.groupby(['State', 'Town']).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: OK. Thanks. Ill try that. I thought the empty cells might be complicating things.